# Migrating SQL 2012 Analysis Services to another server

Tags: sql-server-2012, migration, ssas

We have a SQL Server 2012 installation that was built on...let's say a compromised Windows installation.  It's had so many installs/uninstalls done on it that nothing runs consistently, and we're moving off it to a new clustered instance.  However, I can't seem to get the Analysis Services databases moved.  All the articles I find are about migrating from 2005 or 2008 to 2012, and reference MigrationWizard, which apparently does not exist with SQL Server 2012.

Has anyone moved Analysis Services from one platform to another, both under 2012?

Comment: Is the processing time an important factor? Do you have writeback tables?